# Google Photos backup

Tags: backup, sync, google, google-photos

I've been trying to upload my photos to google photos. It's stuck on uploading x items. I tried restarting, removing cache, clearing storage.
I even tried downgrading the google photos app version.
My backup and sync is on.
Please need help
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Are you using wifi or mobile data for backup
Check this settings/backup & sync and turn on backup and sync
you can also try backup mode/ and reselect high quality
it will auto upload